# Best way to force a user to input an integer in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a simple program in Matlab and am wondering the best way to ensure that the value a user is inputting is a proper integer.

I'm currently using this:

```
while((num_dice < 1) || isempty(num_dice))
    num_dice = input('Enter the number of dice to roll: ');
end
```

However I really know there must be a better way, because this doesn't work all the time. I would also like to add error checking ala a try catch block. I'm brand new to Matlab so any input on this would be great.

**EDIT2:**

```
try
    while(~isinteger(num_dice) || (num_dice < 1))
        num_dice = sscanf(input('Enter the number of dice to roll: ', 's'), '%d');
    end

    while(~isinteger(faces) || (faces < 1))
        faces = sscanf(input('Enter the number of faces each die has: ', 's'), '%d');
    end

    while(~isinteger(rolls) || (rolls < 1))
        rolls = sscanf(input('Enter the number of trials: ', 's'), '%d');
    end
catch
    disp('Invalid number!')
end
```

This seems to be working. Is there anything noticeably wrong with this? isinteger is defined by the accepted answer

Comment: The `catch` part of your try-catch block will never be entered. If the `while` test fails the loop simply stops, i.e. no error is encountered to trigger the `catch`.

Comment: The exceptions were possible from the input function. If you enter something like '<' or '-' on it and try to put it in a variable you get a crash. I've fixed that now by using sscanf

Comment: You may be interested in the function [ROLL](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27327-a-dice-roller-for-matlab), which is a dice roller for Matlab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following can be used directly in your code and checks against non-integer input including empty, infinite and imaginary values:

```
isInteger = ~isempty(num_dice) ...
            && isnumeric(num_dice) ...
            && isreal(num_dice) ...
            && isfinite(num_dice) ...
            && (num_dice == fix(num_dice));
```

The above will only work correctly for scalar input. To test whether a multi-dimensional array contains only integers you can use:

```
isInteger = ~isempty(x) ...
            && isnumeric(x) ...
            && isreal(x) ...
            && all(isfinite(x)) ...
            && all(x == fix(x))
```

**EDIT**

These test for *any* integer values. To restrict the valid values to positive integers add a `num_dice > 0` as in [@MajorApus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236806/best-way-to-force-a-user-to-input-a-integer-in-matlab/5236895#5236895).

You can use the above to force the user to input an integer by looping until they succumb to your demands:

```
while ~(~isempty(num_dice) ...
            && isnumeric(num_dice) ...
            && isreal(num_dice) ...
            && isfinite(num_dice) ...
            && (num_dice == fix(num_dice)) ...
            && (num_dice > 0))
    num_dice = input('Enter the number of dice to roll: ');
end
```

Comment: Yes I've already made a function using yours along with the > 0 part added in. Now I'm wondering how should I be guarding against invalid input right at the input line? What is the best way to re-ask for input when an exception is thrown?

Comment: @Tanner: I added an example usage to my answer that re-asks for input when the user enters invalid input.

Comment: Great thanks. I added in some more code to my original question, is there anything wrong with doing it that way? Something about matlab is killing me. C, C++, C#, Java, VB any of those I would of had this done an hour ago but not matlab!

Comment: @Tanner: Duh, I don't know what I was thinking separating out the logical test from the `while` statement. I edited my answer to reconcile this.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, modify it as needed.

```
function answer = isint(n)

if size(n) == [1 1]
    answer = isreal(n) && isnumeric(n) && round(n) == n &&  n >0;
else
    answer = false;
end
```

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to check the properties of function/user-supplied inputs is to use the [`validateattributes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/validateattributes.html) function. I don't know when this function was first introduced; it may not have been present when the question was first asked, but I think it bears mentioning even though the question is older.

If you want to check that a user-supplied input is a scalar, positive, non-zero, real-valued integer of any numeric data type, you can do so using a [try-catch block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) like so:

```
invalidInput = true;
while invalidInput
  num_dice = input('Enter the number of dice to roll: ');
  try
    validateattributes(num_dice, {'numeric'}, ...
                       {'scalar', 'integer', 'real', 'finite', 'positive'})
    invalidInput = false;
  catch
    disp('Invalid input. Please reenter...');
  end
end
```

If you're dealing with function inputs instead of a user-supplied input, you could also make use of the [`inputParser`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Take the input as a string and use sscanf(http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sscanf.html) to determine if a valid integer was converted from the text.

Comment: I was actually doing this, but it looked ugly to me getting the string, then parsing out a integer from it and then checking the status returned, then jumping into a while loop

Comment: You never said aesthetics were an issue :)  I had forgotten about the "is____()" functions, I just always worry about some edge case that will sneak by your defenses if you use those.

Comment: Yes I just found one in the answer I accepted. Now switched to sscanf to actually parse out the input. With input if you entered an operator (+ - etc) it would throw an exception

Comment: Use the _[A, count, errmsg] = sscanf(...)_ version to make sure the count is equal to 1 and if not use the error message to reprompt, or if it's throwing the exception, catch it like you are doing above.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. I think it is simpler :)

```
% Assume false input at the beginning
checkDice = 0;  

% As long as the input is false, stay in the loop
while ~checkDice
    % Take the input as a string
    strDice = input('Enter the number of dice to roll: ', 's');
    % Convert string to number
    dice = str2num(strDice);

    % Length of dice will be 1 iff input is a single number
    if length(dice) ~=1
        checkDice = 0;
    else
        % Search for a positive integer
        checkDice = ((dice>=1) && dice == floor(dice));   
    end

end
```