# How to avoid enter any i and j value when numeric input is required in matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider I have

> a = input(value = );
>   how can I prevent user from enter i and j as the input values. I would like to have a code some thing like tat
>   if a == any value involves i and j 
>   then break or terminate
>   and prompt the function a = input(value = ) again.

between I have tired something like this, but it doesn't work (the error is still coming out and it unable to prompt the second defined input a = input('enter again')), can anybody explain to me where's the mistake I have done.

```
if ~isnan(x) || ~isnumeric
    a = input('enter again');
else
    continue
end
```

I will really appreciate all the help.

Comment: Check this post about [`numeric` inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236806/best-way-to-force-a-user-to-input-a-integer-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
a = NaN;
while isnan(a) || ~isreal(a)
   a = input('value=','s');
   a = str2double(a);
end
```

Comment: I see...thank you so much...between I got a very basic question that I don't think the need for open a new question. That's what if I need to pause a portion of command in the editor. Normally I'll put a % infront of it but sometimes it's just too many function that I wish to stop it from running..How can it be done..hmmm @Shai

Comment: between for this particular problem I've got only 1 input 'a' right, what if I got a 'a to h' which are 10 inputs that require this condition...do I need to do this one by one for each of them or there's another way round @Shai

Comment: @green make yourself a function `my_input` that wraps around this code. then you can invoke `my_input` every time you need the same functionality. You might want to have `my_input` taking a parameter the string to be printed to the user.

Comment: @green check this [post](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/validateattributes.html) as well. `ValidateAttributes` could give you an idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following to keep on pressing user to enter the values that abide by your conditions. As per my comment, the post gives a great idea of how you can achieve this. It is not using `OR` but `AND` to have a firm condional validation.

```
   while ~(~isempty(a) ...
                && isnumeric(a) ...
                && isreal(a) ...
                && isfinite(a) ...
                && (a == fix(a)) ...
                && (a > 0))
        a = input('Enter the number of dice to roll: ');
    end
```

Comment: I see...thanks...at first I really thought of using OR..thanks ya