# Randomly replace zeros in a matrix with 1s

Tags: matlab

If I create a matrix

```
A = zeros(10,10);
```

How can I write a code that randomly replaces a certain number N of zeros with ones instead? And how can I do it so that the code asks the user what that number N should be?

Comment: Do you wish to implement this in matlab, or use python?

Comment: Those are completely different questions you are asking. Which one you want.

Comment: @IshwarVenugopal Matlab

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`randsample`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) to draw random indices.

```
A = zeros(10);
N = 10;
indices = randsample(numel(A),N); % will return N numbers from the integers 1 to numel(A)
A(indices) = 1; % set these indices to 1
```

Or in one line

```
A(randsample(numel(A), N)) = 1
```

And to let the user choose N:

```
N = input('choose N:');
```

you may need to round that number, or check if it's actually a number, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236806/best-way-to-force-a-user-to-input-an-integer-in-matlab).

Answer (score 0):

This code will switch your zeros into ones randomly and it requests user interaction.

```
A = input('Give your A !');
```

Type the name of your zero matrix or "zeros(n1,n2)"

```
N = input('Give your N !');
```

Type your integer

```
p=randperm(size(A(:),1),N);
A(p)=1;
```

Gives you your new A matrix !